# What does it mean for undefined control sequence?

Tags: math-mode

When I use

```
$(LM)^\ast = (LM)^(0) \ucup (LM)^(1)\ucup (LM)^(2) $
```

I receive an error:

> --this is a undefined control sequence

I need to use `(LM)^*= (LM)^0 \ucap (LM)^1 \ucap..`

and so on. How should I make it in LaTeX?

Comment: Is the problem the `\ast` or the `\ucup`? How about reading up on some basics. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764) Then, in order to find symbols and which packages they may belong to, read [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Answer (score 2):

There is no symbol `\ucup` or `\ucap`; use `\cup` or `\cap`. Also, for superscripts (or subscripts that contain more than one token, brace them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(LM)^\ast = (LM)^{0} \cup (LM)^{1} \cup (LM)^{2}$
\end{document}
```

You can also find many other symbols in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).